# Why can't JavaScript read this C# variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am trying to read a C# property in JavaScript (not using Ajax). In C#, I am setting property on page load. I tried to read this property like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProductId =<%=this.ProductId %>>
    alert(ProductId);   // not successful alert showed undefiend

    function GetValueNow()
    {
        alert(<%=this.ProductId%>); // calling this function was showing value
    }
</script>
```

I tried to access this property in on page load (in the JavaScript of the `.aspx` page) but was not successful. Later, I tried to do this in a JavaScript function, and that worked.

Why can't I read the variable before the body of `GetValueNow()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got an extra `>` sign:

From:

```
var ProductId =<%=this.ProductId %>>
```

To:

```
var ProductId = <%=this.ProductId %>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is just a typo.

```
    var ProductId =<%=this.ProductId %>>
```

should be:

```
    var ProductId =<%=this.ProductId %>;
```